# How to handle a simple click event in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events, javascriptmvc

I am having difficulty with something very simple in Backbone. I want to wire up the `<h1>` in my page so that when the user clicks on it, it returns seamlessly to the homepage, without a postback.

This is the HTML:

```
<h1><a id="home" href="/">Home</a></h1>
```

(UPDATE: fixed ID as suggested by commenter.) And this is my Backbone view and router:

```
var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() { 
    console.log('initializing HomeView');
  },
  events: { 
    "click a#home": "goHome"
  }, 
  goHome: function(e) { 
    console.log('goHome');
    e.preventDefault();
    SearchApp.navigate("/");
  }
});
var SearchApp = new (Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: { 
    "": "index", 
  },
  initialize: function(){
    console.log('initialize app');
    this.HomeView = new HomeView();
  },
  index: function(){
    // do stuff here
  },
  start: function(){
    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
  }
}));
$(document).ready(function() { 
  SearchApp.start();
});
```

The console is showing me

```
initialize  app
initializing HomeView
```

But when I click on the `<h1>`, the page posts back - and I don't see `goHome` in the console.

What am I doing wrong? Clearly I can wire up the `<h1>` click event simply enough in jQuery, but I want to understand how I should be doing it in Backbone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable pushState you need to intercept all clicks and prevent the refresh:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  app.router.navigate(e.target.pathname, true);
});
```

Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() { 
      console.log('initializing HomeView');
    }
  });

  var AboutView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() { 
      console.log('initializing AboutView');
    }
  });

  var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: { 
      "": "index", 
      "about":"aboutView"
    },

    events: function () {
      $('a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        SearchApp.navigate(e.target.pathname, true);
      });
    },

    initialize: function(){
      console.log('initialize app');
      this.events();
      this.HomeView = new HomeView();
    },

    index: function(){
      this.HomeView = new HomeView();
    },

    aboutView : function() {
      this.AboutView = new AboutView();
    }
  });

  var SearchApp = new AppRouter();
  Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});

});
```

Comment: Where should I put that click handler within the backbone code? I know how to write a click handler in jQuery, but I don't know where to put it in Backbone.

Comment: I'm afraid the `Backbone.router.navigate` line in the router code above gives me an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'navigate' of undefined`. I tried changing it to `Router` but that didn't help either. Finally, I changed it to `SearchApp.navigate` and that didn't throw an error, but it also didn't fire the `index` function. Think this is still wrong? I also am not clear why the `HomeView` view is even needed, if we can get `events()` to work properly.

Comment: What version of backbone do you have? Here is the docs: http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate Oh, you need to set the goHome method in the router, not the view.

Comment: Does SearchApp.start(); trigger initialize() ?

Comment: Should be Backbone.history.navigate, not Backbone.router.navigate.

Comment: I've edited the code one last time. This one I tested it and it navigates to the right view without refreshing the page + using pushState.

Comment: I'm afraid this still doesn't work for me with Backbone 0.9.9 and Chrome/MacOS, and the code doesn't look quite right (e.g. it initialises HomeView twice). So I'm leaving the question open for now. Thanks for your help, anyway.

Comment: Hey Richard, hmm, it's weird. I've just created this jsfiddle for ya: http://jsfiddle.net/C7bmX/ The "app" div starts with the text "Loading..." and as soon as the router starts, it hits the initialize function which in turns executes the home view. The homeview renders the new html text "Welcome Home" If you click "about", the click event does not happen as we overrode it, but we do manually trigger the about route using backbone's navigate.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using this code from Artsy, and putting it where you suggested: http://artsy.github.com/blog/2012/06/25/replacing-hashbang-routes-with-pushstate/

Comment: @Richard and anyone else having trouble with this solution: A key difference between artsy's example and the code in this answer is using `$(document).on('click', 'a', ...)` instead of `$('a').click`. These would seem to be equivalent, however only the former worked for me and not the latter, as in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your tag `id` is invalid, try this:

```
<h1><a id="home" href="/">Home</a></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks - I've fixed the tag, but unfortunately it hasn't fixed the problem.