# Using target.pathname in Backbone.Router.navigate() Where to find docs?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, backbone-routing

In this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14199051/3195031

the construction

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        SearchApp.navigate(e.target.pathname, true);
      });
```

was used

Particulaly, this object "e.target.pathname"

I tried to find some docs for javascript event, where property pathname is described, but failed. Maybe somebody can provide a link fo one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.target - is dom object, and in that case its `<a></a>` object. By w3c specs `a` tag implements location interface. So that is the answer where you getting it.
http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#a-interface - for example where you can read it.